# says that main has no attribute 'dbhandler' even thought they are different classes, fairly new to databases and python so could be something dumb

Tags: python, sql

first window is made then when the login button is clicked then it is meant to check if database has them values in database if so login is successful if not then warning. however when it is clicked it says that self.dbhandler is not an attribute to main() even thought they are not in same class.

class stock:
def **init**(self):
self.host = "5.133.180.245"
self.db="horrocksb_A level project"
self.user = "horrocksb_billy"
self.password = "1234password1234"
self.db_connection = mysql.connect(host=self.host,database=self.db,user=self.user,password=self.password)
self.dbhandler = self.db_connection.cursor()

```
def retrieve_data(self):
    self.dbhandler.execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_student")
    result = self.dbhandler.fetchall()
    for item in result:
        print(item)
def check_db(self,user,psswd):
    sql="SELECT*FROM tbl_user WHERE username = %s and password =%s"
    val=user,psswd
    print(val)
    self.dbhandler.execute(sql,val)
    result = self.dbhandler.fetchall()
    if(not result):
        print("No users identified")
        user.text=user.text[:-user.len]
        psswd.text=psswd.text[:-psswd.len]
    for item in result:
        if (user ==item[4] and psswd == item[5]):
            main.LOGIN=True
```

class main:
def **init**(self):
self.LOGIN=False
pygame.init()
self.mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.set_caption('game base')
self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920,1080),0,32)
self.screen_rect=self.screen.get_rect()

```
    self.floor=Floor(self)
    self.base_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 16)
    self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 40)
    self.button1=Button(self,'Log in',860,440,20,100,50)
    self.button3=Button(self,'Quit',1060,540,20,100,50)
    self.button4=Button(self,'Register',1060,440,20,100,50)
    self.button5=Button(self,'Forgot Password',860,540,20,100,50)

    self.inputbox_create()
    self.menu()
def inputbox_create(self):
    self.input_username= inputbox(self,860,240,140,32)
    self.input_password = inputbox(self,860,340,140,32)
    self.input_boxes = [self.input_username,self.input_password]
    
def menu(self):
    while True:
        self.screen.fill((0,0,0))
        self.title()
    
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                self.mouse_pos=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                self.check_button(self.mouse_pos)
            for box in self.input_boxes:
                box.handle_event(event)
        for box in self.input_boxes:
            box.update()
            box.draw()
        if self.LOGIN:
            MainMenu()

                        
        self.button1.draw_button()
        self.button3.draw_button()
        self.button4.draw_button()
        self.button5.draw_button()
        pygame.display.update()
        self.mainClock.tick(60)

def title(self):
    self.label=self.font.render('Welcome',True,(255,255,255))
    self.screen.blit(self.label,(890,100))
    self.username_label=self.base_font.render("Username:", True,(255,255,255))
    self.screen.blit(self.username_label,(860,220))
    self.password_label=self.base_font.render("Password:", True,(255,255,255))
    self.screen.blit(self.password_label,(860,320))


def check_button(self,mouse_pos):
    button_clicked1 = self.button1.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
    button_clicked3 =self.button3.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
    button_clicked4=self.button4.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
    button_clicked5=self.button5.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
    if button_clicked1:
        stock.check_db(self,self.input_username.text,self.input_password.text)
        if self.LOGIN:
            MainMenu()
if __name__ == '__main__':
obj=stock()
sim = main()
```

Comment: Don't do `stock.check_db(self...)`.  You need to create an object of type `stock`, maybe inside `main.__init__`, and store it in a member variable.  Then, call `self.stockobj.check_db(user,pass)`.  You don't want to call the class methods directly.

Comment: Thanks mate i knew it would be something silly